# unique values count in dc.js + crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am stuck at a unique problem involving dc.js and crossfilter. I have some data which i need to display using Number Charts powered by dc.js. However i found minimal documentation for the number charts and hence posting my query.

[Here is the JSFiddle for what i have conceptualized so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/L686qaLs/9/)

I basically want to show the unique project count in box 1 which in this case would be 3, unique place count in box 2 which in this case would be 11 and the screen failure rate which would be 2/15*100 i.e. 15.3%

Currently i have made this working using jquery but thats just a hack. I would like to have these number charts based on cross table aggregation so that i can drill down on the data.

I have come across examples for reductions to calculate counts but they were for bar charts but in the number chart we need to have a value accessor for displaying data.

**Can someone help me out please?**

**PS:** 
Here is the jquery code that i wrote. Dont know if this would be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var baseURL = window.location.origin;

    $.ajax({
        url : baseURL + '/api/PlaceTable',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {},
        async : true,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response) {


            //Project Count
            var projectIdCount = [];
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if(response[i].Project != undefined){
                    if($.inArray(response[i].Project, projectIdCount) === -1){
                        projectIdCount.push(response[i].Project);
                    }                    
                }
            }
            $('#number-box1').text(ProjectIdCount.length);


            //Place Count
            var placeIdCount = [];
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if(response[i].Place != undefined){
                    if($.inArray(response[i].Place, placeIdCount) === -1){
                        placeIdCount.push(response[i].Place);
                    }                    
                }
            }
```

And for displaying a running sum of a column containing binary values i used this code, which worked in the number chart:

```
numberChart
        .valueAccessor(function(x){ return +flag.groupAll().reduceCount().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Flag; }).value();})
        .group(ndx.groupAll());
```

Comment: fiddle updated with groups
https://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/L686qaLs/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failure percentage calculation is a separate problem which I think you've asked elsewhere.  To get the unique count, it is pretty easy to make a "fake groupAll" which returns the number of unique keys in its value method.

We'll also need to filter out the empty bins since crossfilter doesn't do that automatically.

```
function bin_counter(group) {
    return {
        value: function() {
            return group.all().filter(function(kv) {
               return kv.value > 0;
            }).length;
        }
    };
}

var projectGroup = project.group();

projectCount
    .valueAccessor(function(x){ return x;})
    .group(bin_counter(projectGroup));
```

Updated fiddle here, still ignoring the failure% part: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/vct0dzou/1/

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for helping out here. The charts work. But they are not dynamic. I have updated the fiddle here . https://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/0eue2Lak/1/
As you can see, the flag number chart that i have created is dynamic and updates its values as the rowchart is selected. Wonder why this is not so for the place and project count number charts. Also the percentage based number chart, i was unable to implement it using reductio, Could be that i am not too familiar with it. Any pointers for that? 
another fiddle link, just in case
https://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/0sdvmLxo/1/

Comment: Let's take one question at a time, please; it will be more helpful to later readers that way. The reason they weren't updating is that crossfilter doesn't automatically remove empty groups. I'm editing my answer to handle this.

Comment: Looks good to me. I find that with Crossfilter it was necessary to spend a lot of quality time with console.log and console.table to figure out things like the fact that it doesn't filter out empty groups. With regards to Reductio, if you want to use it, you could defined a dimension with a single value and then use exceptionCount for this, but I think the way @Gordon has explained is better, because what you really want to is to count the length of the group array.

Comment: Somehow i was not able to wrap my mind around some key concepts as was solely dependent on tool based BI. But this makes sense. Also for complex groups and math functions reductio would be better so i better get started on that. Ill probably start on building tutorials for reductio as i go along. Thank you both Gordon and Ethan. :)